# how to create our own custom shutdown() and awaitTermination() method of Executor Service?

Tags: multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Basically I want to know how shutdown() and awaitTermination() method internally works in Executor service and if I need to create my own shutdown and awaitTermination() how can I do that?since we know that we Thread.stop() is deprecated, then how this termination is performed in case of Executor framework?

Comment: Is this a [tag:Java] question? Also, could you clarify whether (a) you actually _want_ to create your own shutdown() and awaitTermination() functions for some reason, or (b) you merely are asking how they work?

Comment: P.S., The [`shutdown()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) defined in the stadard Java `ExecutorService` interface is _not_ supposed to terminate any running thread. It only prevents the executor from accepting any new tasks. `shutdownNow()` is almost the same, except that it also [_interrupts_](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/17/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) any running worker threads.